# Slow Select with indexes. How can be improved?

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, select

I run select on a single table (Engine=InnoDB), not too complex but with many rows.

The first select for an id is slower, it takes a few seconds for 9M rows, the next selects are much faster, even when I change the query.

I tried mysql on Windows and mariadb on Linux.

I run select command like this:

```
select `id`,count(*), sum(`counts`) from reference
    where `id`=848
      and `started`<= '2000-01-04 00:00:00'
      and `ended`  >= '2000-01-03 00:00:00';
```

or like this:

```
 select min(`counts`),max(`counts`) from reference where `id`=848 ;
```

it doesn't matter which query was first, the first is slower.

when I run on mariadb on linux consequent id was sometimes fast, but on mysql on windows it was also slow in the first time. this made me think that maybe I missing something.

tests, result and time measure and can be found below.

thanks for any help!

This is my db:

```
create database my_test_db default char set utf8 ;
use my_test_db;
create table items (
    `id` int(11) not null auto_increment, 
    `name` varchar(50), 
    `description` varchar(250) default '', 
    primary key (`id`), 
    unique key item_name_unique(`name`)
);
create table reference (
    `id` int(11) not null,
    `started` datetime not null,
    `ended` datetime not null,
    `counts` int(11) not null,
    key fk_item_id_idx (`id`),
    key idx_started (`started`),
    key idx_ended (`ended`),
    constraint fk_item_id foreign key (`id`) references items(`id`)
              on delete no action on update no action
);
```

A grafic display:

```
MariaDB [my_test_db]> describe items;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(50)  | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(250) | YES  |     |         |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [my_test_db]> describe reference;
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id      | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| started | datetime | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| ended   | datetime | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| counts  | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I used the following program to create 2 infiles:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <random>
#define TM_BUF_SIZE 32

#ifndef WIN32
#define localtime_s(PTM,PTIME_T) localtime_r(PTIME_T,PTM)
#endif
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int id_max, count_iterations, time_frame;
    if(argc!=4)
    {
        std::cerr<<"Missing Arguments!!"<<std::endl;
        std::cerr<<"Usage: DataGen item_count time_iteration time_frame"<<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    id_max  = (int)strtol(argv[1],nullptr,0);
    count_iterations = (int)strtol(argv[2],nullptr,0);
    time_frame = (int)strtol(argv[3],nullptr,0);

    std::random_device r;
    std::default_random_engine re(r());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uni_dist(0, 15);
    std::tm temp, tmStart,tmEnd;
    char bufStart[TM_BUF_SIZE], bufEnd[TM_BUF_SIZE];
    std::memset(&temp, 0, sizeof(tm));

    std::ofstream fitems("items.dat");
    for (int id = 1; id <= id_max; id++)
    {
        fitems << id << "\tid-" << id << "\titem.number." << id << std::endl;
    }
    temp.tm_year = 100;
    temp.tm_mday = 1;
    time_t ts_start = mktime(&temp);
    time_t ts_end;
    int iteration_left = count_iterations;
    std::ofstream frefs("references.dat");
    while(iteration_left--)
    {
        ts_end = ts_start + time_frame;
        localtime_s(&tmStart, &ts_start);
        localtime_s(&tmEnd, &ts_end);
        std::strftime(bufStart, TM_BUF_SIZE, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.0", &tmStart);
        std::strftime(bufEnd, TM_BUF_SIZE, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.0", &tmEnd);
        for (int id = 1; id <= id_max; id++)
        {
            int count = uni_dist(re);
            frefs << id << "\t" << bufStart << "\t" << bufEnd << "\t"<<count<< std::endl;
        }
        ts_start = ts_end;
        if(iteration_left && 0 == iteration_left % 100)
        {
            std::cout<<iteration_left<<" iterations left"<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"Done!"<<std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

copiled it on linux using:

```
g++ -std=c++0x dataGen.cpp -o DataGen
```

run the DataGen program like this:

```
DataGen 3000 3000 60
```

The program create 2 files: "items.dat" and "references.dat"

load the data into DB:

```
use my_test_db;
load data infile '/root/items.dat' into table items;
load data infile '/root/references.dat' into table reference;
```

So I filled the tables with many rows: items with 3K rows and reference with 9M rows.

now I'm running selects on the `reference` table:

Here is the results:

```
#first time for this id: 
MariaDB [my_test_db]> select `id`,count(*), sum(`counts`) from reference where `id`=848 and `started`<= '2000-01-03 00:00:00' and `ended`>='2000-01-02 00:00:00';
+------+----------+---------------+
| id   | count(*) | sum(`counts`) |
+------+----------+---------------+
|  848 |     1442 |         10640 |
+------+----------+---------------+
1 row in set (3.31 sec)

#next query for same id change time filters:
MariaDB [my_test_db]> select `id`,count(*), sum(`counts`) from reference where `id`=848 and `started`<= '2000-01-04 00:00:00' and `ended`>='2000-01-03 00:00:00';
+------+----------+---------------+
| id   | count(*) | sum(`counts`) |
+------+----------+---------------+
|  848 |      121 |           944 |
+------+----------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

#next query for same id change time filters again:
MariaDB [my_test_db]> select `id`,count(*), sum(`counts`) from reference
    where `id`=848
      and `started`<= '2000-01-02 00:00:00'
      and `ended`  >= '2000-01-01 00:00:00';
+------+----------+---------------+
| id   | count(*) | sum(`counts`) |
+------+----------+---------------+
|  848 |     1441 |         10848 |
+------+----------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
```

-- change only id:

```
MariaDB [my_test_db]> select `id`,count(*), sum(`counts`) from reference
    where `id`=1848
      and `started`<= '2000-01-02 00:00:00'
      and `ended`  >= '2000-01-01 00:00:00';
+------+----------+---------------+
| id   | count(*) | sum(`counts`) |
+------+----------+---------------+
| 1848 |     1441 |         10576 |
+------+----------+---------------+
1 row in set (2.63 sec)

#use same id change time filters: 
MariaDB [my_test_db]> select `id`,count(*), sum(`counts`) from reference
    where `id`=1848
      and `started`<= '2000-01-02 12:00:00'
      and `ended`  >= '2000-01-01 12:00:00';
+------+----------+---------------+
| id   | count(*) | sum(`counts`) |
+------+----------+---------------+
| 1848 |     1442 |         10780 |
+------+----------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

#use consequent id is also fast:
MariaDB [my_test_db]> select `id`,count(*), sum(`counts`) from reference
    where `id`=1849
      and `started`<= '2000-01-02 12:00:00'
      and `ended`  >= '2000-01-01 12:00:00';
+------+----------+---------------+
| id   | count(*) | sum(`counts`) |
+------+----------+---------------+
| 1849 |     1442 |         11001 |
+------+----------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.11 sec)
```

-- other query - same id - fast

```
MariaDB [my_test_db]> select min(counts),max(counts) from reference where `id`=1849 ;
+-------------+-------------+
| min(counts) | max(counts) |
+-------------+-------------+
|           0 |          15 |
+-------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

#again it is slow for other id
MariaDB [my_test_db]> select min(counts),max(counts) from reference where `id`=1800 ;
+-------------+-------------+
| min(counts) | max(counts) |
+-------------+-------------+
|           0 |          15 |
+-------------+-------------+
1 row in set (2.36 sec)
```

-- describe query:

```
MariaDB [my_test_db]> describe select `id`,count(*), sum(`counts`) from reference where `id`=1849 and `started`<= '2000-01-02 12:00:00' and `ended`>='2000-01-01 12:00:00';
+------+-------------+-----------+------+--------------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys                        | key            | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+--------------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | reference | ref  | fk_item_id_idx,idx_started,idx_ended | fk_item_id_idx | 4       | const | 2999 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+--------------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it doesn't matter which query was first, the first is slower.

That's because of loading the data from disk, as Gerald explained.

The first query would benefit from

```
INDEX(id, started),
INDEX(id, ended)
```

for the second:

```
INDEX(id, counts)
```

will make it very fast.

InnoDB does not like it when you fail to provide a `PRIMARY KEY`.  Ponder what makes sense for the table `Reference`.

Notice how `DESCRIBE` is less descriptive than `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

It also sounds like you have an unreasonably small value for `innodb_buffer_pool_size` -- this controls the caching.  If you have more than 4GB of RAM, I recommend 70% of available RAM be given to that setting.

Answer (score 1):

If only all questions were so well documented.  A pity there's not really a problem.  Most databases have a memory cache, and when you select data that was selected some moments before, the answer can be found in memory, no need to access disk or other storage.   The elapsed time is depends on the number of rows returned and the amount of processing needed   Comparing datetimes to strings can be expensive, hopefully your databases did it the other way round.

Keep up the good work!

Comment: What I don't understand is why when I change the query but use same id it is also fast? it can't be cashed, and why consequent id query is fast in one os and slow in other?

Comment: It's the data that is cached, not the query result.  I only see the elapsed time increasing when you select another Id, ie. when the data has to be fetched from disk.